# Using Groovy - Add text to a returned date based on the time

Tags: date, groovy

I am running this groovy script:

def sdf = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd kk:mm:ss")

return sdf.format( new Date())

and it returns = 2016-03-23 16:54:39

Which is fine however at the end of the returned value I want to add a space and either AM or PM depending on the what time it is (AM or PM time) as per the below:

AM time returns = 2016-03-23 11:54:39 AM
PM time returns = 2016-03-23 16:54:39 PM

Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you using kk for hours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's even easier with groovy, as Date had a format method;

```
println new Date().format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss a')
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to append AM / PM you can append an 'a' (Am/pm marker) at the end of the date formatter pattern:

```
new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd kk:mm:ss a").format(new Date())
```

This will yield:

```
2016-03-23 18:05:20 PM
```

See the [Java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for the exact details of `SimpleDateFormat`.

Answer (score 0):

## java.time

The `Date` and `SimpleTextFormat` classes are now outmoded by the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built into Java 8 and later.

An [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) is a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with up to [nanosecond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) resolution.

The code in this Answer is Java, as I do not know Groovy syntax.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now();
```

Apply a time zone to get a [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant( instant , zoneId );
```

Define your formatting pattern. These codes in [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) are similar to `SimpleDateFormat` but not exactly the same. Study the class doc.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "yyyy-MM-dd kk:mm:ss" );
```

Be aware that the `kk` used in that particular pattern means 1-24 used for hours of the day instead of 0-23 (`hh`).

Generate a String as a textual representation of your date-time object.

```
String output = zdt.format( formatter );
```